# GeoTools - cropping a coverage doesn't remove rings/holes. Is there a way?

Tags: geotools

Cropping a GeoTools coverage using a polygon geometry works well, for example,

```
WKTReader wktReader = new WKTReader();
Geometry polygon = wktReader.read("Polygon ((-44.84843762765495967 23.50485000755512388, -44.52609517919035653 24.23955870035893767, -43.1982367347690186 24.78673572524395396, -41.84151180242547952 23.49161367821367818, -44.84843762765495967 23.50485000755512388))");
ParameterValueGroup params = processor.getOperation("CoverageCrop").getParameters();
params.parameter("Source").setValue(coverage);
params.parameter("ROI").setValue(polygon);
GridCoverage2D croppedCoverage = (GridCoverage2D)processor.doOperation(params);
```

If the polygon has inner rings (holes), for example

```
"Polygon ((-44.84843762765495967 23.50485000755512388, -44.52609517919035653 24.23955870035893767, -43.1982367347690186 24.78673572524395396, -41.84151180242547952 23.49161367821367818, -44.84843762765495967 23.50485000755512388),(-44.0449870471536471 23.60187575445285546, -43.87659920094079524 23.95848690531703795, -42.91919401818771718 24.08153169162997642, -42.69788427745083226 23.5533718340037872, -44.0449870471536471 23.60187575445285546))"
```

the inner rings are not removed from the resulting "croppedCoverage".

I looked at the cropping code and it seems to explicitly extract the envelope from the input ROI and ignore any inner rings.

I can't find any docs/examples that try to do this and searching doesn't seem to throw up anything. I expect the answer is out there but I'm using the wrong terminology to try and find it.

Can anyone suggest how best to produce a "croppedCoverage" which excludes the pixels covered by inner rings.

Comment: You probably need to raise an enhancement request to handle holes and then submit a fix for it

Comment: Ah, Ok thanks Ian. Just knowing that it is working as intended is a good start. I can maybe come up with a work around.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is as intended but it looks like what is implemented currently, should be a relatively easy fix